# showing loader while loading and show result when finished works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, loading, show

I have a familytree site that can produce a complete tree (may show thousands of members) which takes some time to figure out. So while loading it shows a picture of a growing tree, and when ready it shows the actual family tree. Works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome it produces an empty page when loaded.

Here is how I did it:

html:

`<body onload='JavaScript:show();'> <div id='loader'>...<img ...></div> <div id='tree' class='hidden'>... tree ...</div>`

css:

```
`.hidden {display: none;}`
```

Javascript:

```
`function show()
{
   let temp = document.getElementById ('loader');
   let tree = ocument.getElementById('tree');
   temp.hidden = true;
   dump.hidden = false;
   dump.style.display = 'block';
}`
```

I was expecting to have the same result in Chrome as in Firefox. FF shows the build tree after loading, but Chrome shows an empty page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a type error in your JavaScript function.
Instead of this:

```
let tree = ocument.getElementById('tree');
```

Update your code to this:

```
let tree = document.getElementById('tree');
```

However, in your function, the `**dump**` variable is not defined anywhere else. Indeed, the functions work well in my local environment.

```
function show() {
    let temp = document.getElementById('loader');
    let tree = document.getElementById('tree');
    temp.hidden = true;
    tree.hidden = false;
    tree.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Taranjeet Singh, it now works fine in my local environment.
But to my surprise it works differently after uploading to my online server:
The temporary dev is not show there.
I tried an
ini_set ('output_buffering', '4096');
in combination with:
echo str_pad ($wait, 4096, ' ');
after the temporary dev is written.
This works fine in the local environment, but the online server does not show the temporary dev, only the full tree after loading has finished.

Comment: Please consider removing this as an answer and putting it as a comment to Taranjeet answer instead since you're replying to him with this and not answering the question.